# Show a Basic Webpage in Basic4Android?

Tags: webview, basic4android

I am looking everywhere ad just cant to find a good answer to this. I looked everywhere but found nothing Read all of the html and webview tutorials too. So what i have done is that i have a new project in the basic4android. All i want to do is display a webpage thats full screen. I have tried many different code and i found [one here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/10465-how-display-website.html) that made sense but still did not work for me. **But is there anyone that can show me how to show a basic webpage in Basic4Android???**

```
Sub MyOfficeWeb
  Dim myw As WebView
  myw.Initialize("myw")
  Activity.AddView(myw, 0, 0, 100%x, 100%y) 'Your options for size here
  myw.LoadUrl("http://www.yourwebsite.com")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with me. Here is my full code:

```
Sub Process_Globals
End Sub

Sub Globals
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
  MyOfficeWeb
End Sub

Sub MyOfficeWeb
  Dim myw As WebView
  myw.Initialize("myw")
  Activity.AddView(myw, 0, 0, 100%x, 100%y) 'Your options for size here
  myw.LoadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
End Sub

Sub Activity_Resume
End Sub

Sub Activity_Pause (UserClosed As Boolean)
End Sub
```